# Code for cropping an image using AsyncFileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using an AsyncFileUpload tool for uploading images in a registration form. But, I have a problem in that, if anyone will try to upload a photo larger than 30kb, the size of the database may increase. So I would like to give a provision for users to upload their large photo using the AsyncFileUpload control and provide a cropping mechanism. If anyone know the idea, please tell me.

Comment: So are you saying if millions of people upload 29kb images, the database size won't increase?

Comment: I would like to save images only less size on 30kb. So the users will have a provision for cropping the image without any damage.

Comment: So why not just have a stipulation that images can't be > 30 kb? You can check for the size much easier than you can provide cropping functionality. Do you really want to re-invent Photoshop on your registration form?

Comment: I don't know how to give such a functionality to users when using the registration form. Is this simple for a less computer knowledge user ?

Comment: If you believe that they will be able to crop an image on your web site in real time, I think they'll be savvy enough to know what 30 kb means.

Comment: [You should also do some reading on whether you want to store images in the database or might be better off putting them on the file system (where storage space is much cheaper and more efficient)](https://www.google.com/webhp?rlz=1C1CHFA_enUS493US493&sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&rlz=1C1CHFA_enUS493US493&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=should%20I%20store%20images%20on%20filesystem%20or%20in%20the%20database&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=89dccf89cf1c3a70&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=2237&bih=1082).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can resize the image to a size that you are alright storing.
2. Change file name to a `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`.
3. Store that guid in the database for the user's image.

You will save database space that way, and resizing the image gives you control over what is acceptable.  If they 'crop' to the maximum size, then you could have huge files.

Comment: [Let me google that for you](https://www.google.com/webhp?rlz=1C1DVCC_enUS346&sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&rlz=1C1DVCC_enUS346&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=c%23%20image%20resize&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=61fd8198cacac0fb&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1511&bih=1039)